# How to install Spidermonkey JS SHell

Tags: javascript, linux, installation, spidermonkey

Hey there :) Complete Linux Noob here. For My course at univerisity I need to install the
Spidermonkey Js Shell.

https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/nightly/latest-mozilla-central/

so far I have only downloaded and unpacked the files (js  libnspr4.so  libplc4.so  libplds4.so) but I have no clue how to install these files.

as an alternative I also found these commands to install the Jshell on this site
https://askubuntu.com/questions/892498/how-to-install-and-configure-mozilla-spidermonkey-js-engine-in-ubuntu-server-16
however, I don't have a clue if that is exactly what I need

Thanks in advance for your help

BR

Comment: Does it run correctly without installing? If so you could manually copy it to somewhere in your $PATH

Comment: How can I test that ? Just by typing the shell command ?

Comment: I'm guessing that `js` is an executable file, so if you navigate to that dir in a terminal and run `./js` you can see if it runs as expected

Comment: It seems to work a  js> appears now

Comment: Neat. Yeah you can probably just move all the files to one of the directories listed in `echo $PATH`, or look up how to add a new directory to it

Comment: Thank you very much :) by adding the Js File into the $PATH I would not have to go to the directory where the file is stored and to execute the file every time right?

Comment: Right, you will be able to run `js` instead of `/path/to/js`

Comment: Is there a directory in which I should put it?  - a best practice so to say

Comment: `/home/yourname/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` would be the obvious places, but they may not be in your PATH by default

Comment: Awesome !! Thank you very much !!